# RxSwift: Ambiguous reference to member 'items(cellIdentifier:cellType:)'

Tags: swift, uitableview, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I trying setup `tableView` datasource binding with `RxSwift (3.6.1)` but I am getting an error when building the app:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'items(cellIdentifier:cellType:)'

Here just simple Observable from Array just for test:

[image: Here just simple <code>Observable</code> from <code>Array<Int></code> just for test]

P.S. viewController's `tableView` is connected in the Storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a little `)` between the `)` and the `{`!

The correct code should be:

```
    let test = Observable.just([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "pokatushkaCell")) {
//                                              ^
        row, item, cell in
    }
```

Note where the arrow is pointing. You missed that `)`, making Swift think that you want to call `items` with two arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i just started use with Rx )